# append object to specific dynamic div jquery

Tags: javascript, append, show-hide, appendchild, prepend

element to append (to spesific div child):

```
<object width="305" height="20" data="player.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<param value="transparent" name="wmode"><param value="player.swf" name="music">
<param value="mp3=http://linkfrom/a/songs.mp3&amp;loop=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp;showvolume=1&amp;autostart=true&amp;width=305" name="FlashVars">
</object>
```

to one of this id.

```
<div id="div1">
<a id="link1" href="http://linksto.com/songs1.mp3">hide</a>
<div id="showhere1"></div>
</div>
<div id="div2">
<a id="link2" href="http://linksto.com/songs2.mp3">hide</a>
<div id="showhere2"></div>
</div>
<div id="div3">
<a id="link3" href="http://linksto.com/songs2.mp3">hide</a>
<div id="showhere3"></div>
</div>
```

say i click first link with id= "link1" new element will added inside  and text link will be change to "hide".
see example after click:

```
<div id="div1">
<a id="link1" href="http://linksto.com/songs1.mp3">hide</a>
<div id="showhere1"><object data="player.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"><param value="transparent" name="wmode"><param value="player.swf" name="music"><param value="mp3=http://www.radiosalomon.si/scripts/player/7.mp3&amp;loop=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp;showvolume=1&amp;autostart=true&amp;width=305" name="FlashVars"></object></div>
</div>
<div id="div2">
<a id="link2" href="http://linksto.com/songs2.mp3">show</a>
<div id="showhere2"></div>
</div>
<div id="div3">
<a id="link3" href="http://linksto.com/songs2.mp3">show</a>
<div id="showhere3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you want to append player after every link. For that You can use following script:

```
jQuery('a').click(function(){
   event.preventDefault()
   var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    if(jQuery(this).text() == 'show'){
        console.log( jQuery(this).next('div'));
         jQuery(this).next('div').html('<object data="player.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"><param value="transparent" name="wmode"><param value="player.swf" name="music"><param value="mp3=http://www.radiosalomon.si/scripts/player/7.mp3&amp;loop=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp;showvolume=1&amp;autostart=true&amp;width=305" name="FlashVars"></object>');
        jQuery(this).text('hide')
    }else{
        jQuery(this).next('div').html('')
         jQuery(this).text('show')
    }

});
```

You can change object value as per your code.

Here is the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/xEKcz/

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: your code look great, but it not work with my previous html code, when i click the link it direct to mp3 link. your link on http://jsfiddle.net/xEKcz/ not work also.

Comment: Is your previous html is different from what I have used in fiddle?

Comment: no, I'm using the same html code.
it's just that when I test in the link you gave does not work as well.
so I clicked on the link "hide" link directly access the mp3, it should open the flash player.